# mysql trigger set variable from php

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

```
$query="
CREATE TRIGGER history_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON config FOR EACH ROW
Begin
DECLARE oid int(11);
DECLARE oname varchar(10);

DECLARE ipadd varchar(16);
SET oid='$operatorId';
SET oname='$operatorname';



if new.description!=old.description then
    insert into log (operatorId, operatorname, columnname, rowid, newdata, olddata) values
    (oid, oname, 'description', old.id, new.description, old.description);
end if;
end;
";
mysql_query($query);
```

I need php variable insert into log table while trigger start.
I try edit '$operatorId','$operatorname' in $query string, but I see '$operatorId' the string in the new row not the correct Id.
How to make the php variable in to mysql trigger query? Please help, thank you.

Comment: not possible. The php variable will be set **ONCE**, when the create trigger string is built in PHP. after that, whatever the var is GONE, and only the text it contained will remain. MySQL also cannot "reach out" into php to get a new/updated value when the trigger executes - how could it. mysql has **NO** idea where the trigger definition came from - it only sees what query text comes in. the particular script instance that created that var will also be long dead/gone.